# Cake PHP Validation (+ preg_match()-warning)

Tags: php, cakephp

using cakephp 2.0 rc3.

following validation in my model:

```
var $validate = array(
        'loginname' => array(
            'minCharactersRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 3),
            ),
            'alphaNumericRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            ),
            'uniqueRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
            ),
            'on' => 'create',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'minCharactersRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', 5),
            ),
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
        ),

        'email' => array(
            'emailRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('email'),
            ),
            'uniqueRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
            ),
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmtpy' => false,
        ),

        'display_name' => array(
            'betweenRule' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 3, 20),
            ),
            'uniqueRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
            ),
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
        ),

        'registered' => array(
            'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'),
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'create'
        ),

        'status' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'required' => false,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'create'
        ),
    );
```

when i fill out every field and submit im getting "required" error messages...
debug($this->Model->validationErrors) says:

```
Array(
[loginname] => Array
    (
        [0] => required
    )

[password] => Array
    (
        [0] => required
    )

[email] => Array
    (
        [0] => required
    )

[display_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => required
    ))
```

in addition some ugly warnings appear:

```
Warning (2): preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2981]
```

(4 times)

when i saw it the first time, i thought i misstyped anything, but after checking 3-4 times and getting the same error, i decided to come here to ask :x
am i missing anything? running out of ideas ...

nahri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading the cookbook examples again, i found the solution.

every single rule must have the required, allowEmpty, etc, parameters given, not the field itself.

this makes no sense to me, but thats how it is described in the manual and how it works..

Answer (score -1):

`required => true` does not mean the same as the validation rule `notEmpty()`. `required => true` indicates that the array key must be present - it does not mean it must have a value. Therefore validation will fail if the field is not present in the dataset, but may (depending on the rule) succeed if the value submitted is empty `('')`.

So in your case you can comment out all the `required => true` and all should be fine.

Comment: i know the difference between notEmpty and required and the fields are present in request data, i tested that. 

it must be something else (the warnings cause of preg_match()?)

Comment: I agree that there shoudnt be any warnings no matter what "required" is set to.